# Proper way of update multiple elements in list type field

Tags: cassandra

My table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE mids.defect_data (
                  wafer_id text, 
                  document_id text,
                  defect_id text,
                  fields list<double>,
                  primary key((wafer_id), defect_id)
                );
```

`fields` column has `list` type of `double` with ~500 length in my case.

Now, I'd like to update range of elements in `fields`(for example. `fields[0] ~ fields[19]`).

What approach should I use?. please be noted that the update indexes may vary(for example, sometime `{fields[0]~fields[20]},`sometimes`{fields[0], field[1], field[10], field[15],....} )`

I'm working on service in c# and using Datastax Cassandra C# driver.

P.S : I'm now afraid of my modeling is not properly designed in this case.

Comment: I don’t think you will be able to update the range of a list in dB what you can do is fetch the date before updating the list and then update the dB with updated list.

Comment: @RamanMishra ah... that's bad. currently fetching ~30000 rows spend ~31 sec in my setup.  :-(  .

Comment: It seems you are not fetching the data in parallel see executeAsync

Comment: it's better to rethink your data model, and maybe model as separate rows for values. List type has quite many problems in Cassandra

Comment: @alex-ott hmm when i did that, 30000 x 500 rows took over minutes to insert and fetch.  and when i used async version as raman-mishra mentioned,  too many in flight request exception was caught :-(

Comment: You can either increase number of in-flight requests, or use some Semaphore to limit a number of requests. For example with such code: https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/SessionLimiter.java

Comment: @AlexOtt Thanks you for the code hint. I'll try.